# How to decode a QByteArray using UTF-8 with Latin-1 fallback

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, qstring

I have a socket connected to an IRC server. I would like to convert received data (QByteArray) to QString. Because on IRC, not everyone is using UTF-8, I want to try to decode the QByteArray using UTF-8:

```
QString s = QString::fromUtf8(array);
```

The problem is that Qt silently replaces "bad" characters and always returns a QString. I would like to "try" decoding, and if it can't decode correctly, fallback to latin-1 decoding.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like Qt offers a decoding routine that allows its handling of invalid sequences to be configured.

Instead you should be able to do something like the following:

```
QString s = QString::fromUtf8(array);
if (s.toUtf8() != array) {
  s = QString::fromLatin1(array);
}
```

Direct conversion between UTF-8 and UTF-16 (i.e., no normalization) should be loss-less and perfectly reversible. If converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8 does not produce the original data, then that's because the original data wasn't valid UTF-8.

It is possible, though unlikely in normal circumstances, that text in some other encoding happens to be valid UTF-8 but have different meaning in UTF-8 vs. the correct encoding. Such text will be detected as UTF-8 by this and will not display as intended. The only way to avoid this is to have prior knowledge of the correct encoding, e.g. via protocol declarations of the correct encoding.

---

Another option is to use `std::wstring_convert`, part of the C++11 standard library.

```
#include <codecvt> // for codecvt_utf8_utf16
#include <locale>  // for wstring_convert

QByteArray array = ...

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> converter;
QString s;
try {
  std::u16string s16 = converter.from_bytes(array.data(), array.size());

  s = QString::fromUtf16(s16.c_str());

} catch(...) {
  s = QString::fromLatin1(array);
}
```

Note that the use of `fromUtf16` with `char16_t` depends on [this change](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/commit/b2d5e7805abe569a926eb087a75bd903261b734f) which may not be included in the version of Qt you're using. Presumably they'll also eventually add something like `fromStdU16String()` so you can say `QString::fromStdU16String(s16)`, or maybe add implicit conversions so you can just say `s = s16;`.

Also note that libstdc++ (the default standard library implementation for gcc) doesn't include this conversion facility yet. Visual Studio 2010 and later has it, and libc++ has it.